# What is the expected behavior of applying Ruby's match operator to nil?

Tags: ruby, null

What is the expected behavior of applying Ruby's match operator to `nil`?
Specifically, what should happen to the capture variables and why?

This code

```
"a1c" =~ /.*(\d).*/
puts $1
nil =~ /.*(\d).*/
puts $1
puts $1.nil?
```

Produces this result:

```
1
1
false
```

My understanding is that a failed match resets all the capture variables to `nil`. If that is the case, why is `$1` sill 1 after the attempted match with `nil`?

(I tried to find documentation explaining the expected behavior; but, my Google skills failed me.)

Comment: You would typically use the global variables only after a successful match, e.g. via `if obj =~ pattern`

Comment: I suggest you remove the tag `null` as it is a foreign concept in Ruby. `nil` would be more apt but I doubt if anyone would search for the tag, but if they did it seems highly improbable that these answers would be what they are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point with `NilClass#=~` is that it does not fail to match. It always returns `nil`.

Quote from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/NilClass.html#method-i-3D%7E):

> ```
> nil =~ other → nil
> ```
>
> Dummy pattern matching – always returns nil.

Looking at its source code, this method is extremely simple and does nothing but returning `nil`:

```
               static VALUE
nil_match(VALUE obj1, VALUE obj2)
{
    return Qnil;
}
```

This [conversation in the Ruby issue tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15231) might be relevant in this context too.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby < 3.2.0, `NilClass#=~` is actually implemented by its parent class `Object` in [`Object#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.9/Object.html#method-i-3D%7E). This is a fallback method which can be overridden by subclasses of `Object`, such as `String` or `Regexp`. The `Object#=~` method was deprecated in Ruby 2.6.0 and was finally removed in Ruby 3.2.0. These versions implement [`NilClass#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/NilClass.html#method-i-3D%7E) directly though.

The basic `Object#=~` resp. `NilClass#=~` method perform no matching on their own but just returns `nil` without setting / resetting any of the global magic variables. This has the effect that the method is available on all objects but only performs a meaningful action on objects which implement an overridden method.